# Flutter application immediately closing

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter

My Flutter application written for my iphone runs on it in development mode, but as soon as I turn off run, I can't open the application from my phone. It opens and closes immediately. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

I expect that after I develop the app, I would be able to use it locally on my device.

Comment: You can't run a debug build unless you are running under the debugger. Install a release or profile build

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, , indeed, you need to go to xcode, and create a release scheme, after which the application can be run locally